# ASP.NET MVC Unit Test for testing CSRF attacks?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, csrf

How can I write an integration/unit test to pass the CSRF attacks in order to write a passing test for my CRUD operations?

How should I send a CSRF token to the controller that use the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute in my unit test project?

*Note: I use NUnit framework as my Test Framework.*

**Edit:**

I don't want to test the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute and I know that it isn't best practices. but in order to pass my unit tests where I've written this attribute (CRUD), I should provide it. otherwise, it won't pass my unit tests.

Comment: You do not need to test the framework - its already been thoroughly tested. Write tests to test **your** code

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I don't want to test the ValidateAntiForgeryToken, actually, in order to pass my CRUD operations, I should pass the CSRF tokens. Otherwise, my unit test won't pass.

Comment: Testing an action, is by definition, not a unit test; it's an integration test. This type of integration testing is best left to automated UI testing scenarios, where you can actually script the steps to the process: namely, actually loading the initial form view that sets the anti forgery token.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks. Well, the UI testing is the type of the test that I should consider for this scenario. So kindly post it as your answer and I'll mark it as the answer.